# Why the SharedPreference always get the unsorted arraylist in Android?

Tags: android, arraylist, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I am develop in Android , and try to writing `ArrayList` into `SharedPreferencesString`

I use the following function to set and get data:

```
fun setSharedPreferencesMutableList(context: Context, setName: String, value: ArrayList<String>) {
    val setting = context.getSharedPreferences(TABLE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    setting.edit().putStringSet(setName, value.toSet()).apply()
}

fun getSharedPreferencesMutableList(context: Context, getName: String): ArrayList<String> {
    val setting = context.getSharedPreferences(TABLE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    var array =  setting.getStringSet(getName, setOf<String>()).toTypedArray()
    return ArrayList(Arrays.asList(*array))
}
```

I save the ArrayList first , and want to save again after sort the `Arraylist`. But I always get the pre-sorting data.

The Code like the following:

```
var test = ArrayList<String>()
test.add("111")
test.add("222")
test.add("333")
test.add("444")
test.add("555")
//The data should be: [111, 222, 333, 444, 555]

//Save Data
SharedPreferenceHelper.setSharedPreferencesMutableList(context,SharedPreferenceHelper.TEST,test)

//Change "111" with "444"
var i = test.indexOf("444")
var data = test[0]
test[0] = "444"
test[i] = data
//The data should be: [444, 222, 333, 111, 555]

//Save Data again
SharedPreferenceHelper.setSharedPreferencesMutableList(context,SharedPreferenceHelper.TEST,test)

Log.d(TAG, "getList: ${SharedPreferenceHelper.getSharedPreferencesMutableList(context, SharedPreferenceHelper.TEST)}")
```

But I always get the unsorted data([111, 222, 333, 444, 555]) when I get SharedPreference.

Did I missing something ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First change `apply()` to `commit();`

Answer (score 1):

> Did I missing something ?

yes, the fact the `Set` is an unordered collection of items. Either you perform the sorting in your `getSharedPreferencesMutableList` before returning it, or you store it differently EG as JSON array string